# Azure Container Registry App Service AzureFiles mounting

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry, azure-files, storage-file-share

I have an application which is built by Dockerfile and deployed to the Container Registry Repository and
I have an App Service in Azure Resource Group which run from this Azure Container Registry Repository (terraform script) like this:

```
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL      = "https://<NAME>.azurecr.io"
```

The problem is that I need to mount some data, e.g. /data directory more than 100 GB, like in Storage Account File Share AzureFiles (for read and write) but I cannot because I am using Docker container in App Service and I cannot mount data in container.
Could I do it and how? If yes, could I do it through the terraform script or yaml?

I tried to mount it in File Share, but it mounted only in App Service path, not in Docker container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Mount Azure Storage as a local share in App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=container-linux) documentation. What's most important is that your mount path should match the directory inside your docker image. This [video](https://youtu.be/q7J050yovuo?t=147) does a great job of how-to setup the feature.